# Sort Pandas Dataframe based on previous row value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
Name      Previous Name
Alice     NaN
Charlie   Bob
Bob       Alice
Fred      Eddy
Danny     Charlie
Eddy      Dan
```

I would like to sort the dataframe so that is looks like:

```
Name      Previous Name
Alice     NaN
Bob      Alice
Charlie  Bob
Danny    Charlie
Eddy     Danny
Fred     Eddy
```

I know the boolean test involves something like

```
dataframe['Value'] = dataframe['PreviousValue'].shift(1)
```

But how can I use that as a sort criteria?

EDIT: Changed example from letters to names

Answer (score 0):

Sort of values, then shift:

```
df = df.sort_values('Value')
df['Previous Value'] = df['Value'].shift()
```

Output:

```
  Value Previous Value
0     A            NaN
2     B              A
1     C              B
4     D              C
5     E              D
3     F              E
```

Comment: Would this override the values in df['Previous Value']?

Comment: Yes. You can remove the second line though.

Comment: Would this work if the values were random numbers instead of letters?

Comment: As long as they care of the same type. Wouldn't work if you have mixed typed, e.g. `[1, 'a']`, or mutable values, e.g. `list` inside the cells.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without overriding the values in df['Previous Value']? I have a feeling to use the index to help sort, like:
`for row in df:
df[:row].loc = df['Previous Value' == df['Value' i+1]].loc +1`

Comment: just `df = df.sort_values('Value')` would work.